# Associating one file extension with another in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm working on a PHP project where all files are given the extension '.shtml'.  Unfortunately Vim doesn't know to highlight PHP in these files.  Is there as way to force Vim to highlight these files as PHP instead of shtml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this to your .vimrc

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.shtml set filetype=php
```

also... the quick-fix when you're already in vim:

```
:set filetype=php
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also add something like

```
<?php /* vim:set ft=php: */
```

in the beginning of your file. That would make it more or less independent of the local vim settings.

Comment: You can also add these modeline options to the end of the files